# Bokeh annular_wedge plot in datetime type figure

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I'm trying to use bokeh library to plot some annular_wedge in a figure, but when I use the x_axis_type="datetime" in figure kargs, nothing is plotted. My objective is to make something like matlab stick plot for directional wind.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

#x=[1, 2, 3] #some x samples
x = [datetime.today() + timedelta(days=aux) for aux in range(3)] #some datetime samples

y=[1, 2, 1.5]
a=[1.5,3.0,4.5] #some start_angle for wedge_annulus
b=[1.5+0.1,3.0+0.1,4.5+0.1] # some end_angle for wedge_annulus

p = figure(width=400, height=400,x_axis_type="datetime") #when figure is datetime type, there is no plot.

p.annular_wedge(x, y, inner_radius=0.1, outer_radius=0.55, 
                start_angle=a, end_angle=b ,color="red", alpha=0.6, legend="q")

show(p)
```

After some time I understood that the problem should be the scale of x axis, that in datetime must be ^12 elevated. I tried to multiply the inner_radius and outer_radius by ^ 12 (datetime -> timestamp), but I still having troubles to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final version of the code. Now it work the way I need.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

x = [(datetime.today() + timedelta(days=aux)) for aux in range(3)] #some datetime samples

y=[1, 2, 1.5]
a=[1.5,3.0,4.5] #some start_angle for annular_wedge
b=[1.5+0.1,3.0+0.1,4.5+0.1] # some end_angle for annular_wedge

p = figure(width=400, height=400,x_axis_type="datetime") #when figure is datetime type, there is no plot.

p.annular_wedge(x, y, inner_radius=0, outer_radius=0.3*(10**8),  
                start_angle=a, end_angle=b ,color="red", alpha=0.6, legend="q")

show(p)
```